# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un buscador de palabras en un texto en c#?

Tags: c#

Como hago un buscador de palabras que recibe un texto y devuelve las palabras más relevantes, las sugerencias y en que texto aparecen

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se que esperas como respuesta.. es como que necesitas todo un sistema completo no?

Comment: Carlos, como te comenta @gbianchi deberias completar tu pregunta con el codigo que que tienes de prueba o quieres mejorar. Pero para que vayas realizando tu demo o pruebas te dejo [Cómo buscar cadenas en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings) y tambien [Procedimientos recomendados para la comparación de cadenas en .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings). Pero todo depende de donde esta el texto (si en memoria, disco, db, etc) porque incluso existen mejoras formas de indexar dicho texto para su busqueda.

Comment: Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Algo como esto podría ayudarte, pero evidentemente debes especificar más lo que necesitas ya que de alguna manera debes tener un listado de palabras relevantes para que el programa sepa lo que quieres buscar en el texto.

aquí te dejo el código: 

public static void BuscarPalabra(string textoCompleto, params string[] palabrasRelevantes)
        {
            //Hacemos minúsculas para que no haya problemas de sensibilidad
            textoCompleto = textoCompleto.ToLowerInvariant();
            foreach (string palabraRelevante in palabrasRelevantes)
            {
               string palabraR = palabraRelevante.ToLowerInvariant();

                //Verificamos que la palabra buscada existe en el texto
                if (textoCompleto.Contains(palabraR))
                {
                    //Separamos el texto dependiendo del caracter separador (En español suele ser el espacio, comas, saltos de línea, punto y coma, entro algunos otros separadores)
                    string[] BloqueSaltoLinea = textoCompleto.Split('\u000A');
                    foreach (string bloque in BloqueSaltoLinea)
                    {
                        string[] bloqueEspacioEnBlanco = bloque.Split('\u0020');
                        for(int i= 0; i<bloqueEspacioEnBlanco.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (bloqueEspacioEnBlanco[i].Equals(palabraR))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"La palabra '{palabraR}' se encuentra en el texto '{bloque}' en la posicion: {i+1}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"La palabra {palabraR} no se encuentra en este texto");
                }
            }  
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string textoLargo = "Yo ofrezco desnudas\n, vírgenes, intactas y sencillas, para mis delicias y el placer de mis amigos\n, estas noches árabes vividas, soñadas y traducidas\n" +
                " sobre su tierra natal y sobre el agua\n Ellas me fueron dulces durante los ocios en remotos mares,\n bajo un cielo ahora lejano. Por eso las doy.";

            string[] palabrasBuscadas = { "desnudas", "sencillas" };

            BuscarPalabra(textoLargo, palabrasBuscadas);
        
        }
    }
```